# Kivy Widget not moving

Tags: python, kivy

When the program runs, the `ScreenManager` shows the Main screen on which I added the white little `square(Ball)`.

The *widget Ball* should be moving around but I cannot figure out why it is still static. 
The update method is working but the position of the widget is not being updated. I tried to move things around and no effect.

If someone could help me to understand where I am wrong, would be great. Thx so much.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window  import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

# simple Screen on which the ball should move
class Main(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Ball())
        with self.canvas.before:
            Rectangle(source = 'BG1.png',
                      size = Window.size,
                      pos = self.pos)

# the Ball should be bouncing around
class Ball(Widget):
    velocity = ListProperty([10, 15])
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Ball, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval (self.update, 1 / 60)

        with self.canvas:
            Rectangle (color=[0, 0, 0, 1],
                       size=(10, 10),
                       pos = self.pos)

    def update(self, *args):
        print('wtf')
        self.x += self.velocity[0]
        self.y += self.velocity[1]

        if self.x < 0 or (self.x + self.width) > Window.width:
            self.velocity[0] *= -1
        if self.y < 0 or (self.y + self.height) > Window.height:
            self.velocity[1] *= -1

Window.size = (400, 300)
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Main(name = 'main'))

class Bubble(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Bubble().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Embryo and John, your answers led me to find the right answer. I found this code on this blog. Solved it all:[Kivy blog](https://blog.kivy.org/2014/10/updating-canvas-instructions-declared-in-python/)

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color

class CornerRectangleWidget(Widget)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CornerRectangleWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 0, 0, 1)  # set the colour to red
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=self.center,
                                  size=(self.width/2.,
                                        self.height/2.))

        self.bind(pos=self.update_rect,
                  size=self.update_rect)

    def update_rect(self, *args):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = self.size
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you set up `Canvas` instructions in python (rather than in `kv`), you don't get the automatic bindings that `kv` does for you. So the `Rectangle` that you define in the `Ball.__init__()` method gets its `pos` defined as the `pos` of the `Ball` at its `__init__()` moment (which is [0,0]), and it does not change automatically. You can fix that by doing the update yourself. First, in your `Ball.__init__()` change your `with self.canvas` block to:

```
    with self.canvas:
        Color(0,0,0,1)
        self.rect = Rectangle (size=(10, 10),
                   pos = self.pos)
```

One change is defining the `Color`, and the second is creating a reference to the `Rectangle`. Then in your update method add the line:

```
self.rect.pos = self.pos
```

This will move the rectangle with the Ball position.

Also, your `update` method has some problems because the `size` of the `Ball` is the same size as the `Window`. It is not the `size` you provide in the `Rectangle`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what is happening is this...

You are drawing the rectangle once, when you instantiate the `Ball` widget.
This is what you see in the bottom left corner.
After that you move the widget, but you don't draw it again.

If you `print(self.pos)` in the update function, you'll see it moving...